# Match and compare timestamps with regex on Windows command line

Tags: regex, windows, cmd

I need a regex to compare different time-lengths.

```
Duration: 00:04:55.80, start: 0.000000
Duration: 00:04:58.80, start: 0.000000
```

I have the input as a string and need the output

```
Difference 3s
```

Comment: And have you any attempt to show?

Comment: You can use this regex `Duration: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}), start: 0.000000 Duration: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}), start: 0.000000` for extracting the durations values. However, you'd need something to convert those extracted durations to a time datatype.

Comment: i dont have any attempt a this time. i am not familiar with the windows shell. would appreciate some examples how to use regexes in windows and how to convert the time as a timestamp

Comment: You need a routine to calculate elapsed time, not regexp.